# Groovy sort colors of the rainbow

Tags: sorting, groovy

Given that the rainbow colors are ordered exactly like this: ROYGBIV (R=red, O=orange, Y=yellow, G=green, B=blue, I = indigo, and V=violet) how do I take a list:

```
def partialUnorderedList =["orange", "blue", "red","green"]
```

and sort it into ROYGBIV order resulting in:

```
def  partialOrderedList = ["red", "orange", "green", "blue"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my take on the problem:

```
def order = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"]
def input = ["orange", "blue", "red", "green"]

def sorted = input.sort { order.indexOf it }
```

It uses the index position in the reference list for a given element from the input list as the sort criterion.

Comment: well can someone say me from where does `indexOf` comes for `order`?

Comment: @Ant's http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Thanks Christoph. That's the exact solution I came up with as well. Another interesting option would be to use an Enum, yet another a Map. Anyone care to provide those for a few extra points? :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution for your problem :

```
def a =["red","orange","yellow","green","blue","indigo","violet"]
def input = ["orange", "blue", "red","green"]
list = []
for(i=0;i<input.size();i++)
{
   index =  a.findIndexValues{ it ==  input[i]}.join() as Integer
   list[index] =  input[i]
}
println list.minus(null)
```

outputs:

```
[red, orange, green, blue]
```

For other inputs :

```
[yellow, red, blue, orange, violet, indigo]
```

it outputs:

```
[red, orange, yellow, blue, indigo, violet]
```

Have used [findIndexValues](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#findIndexValues%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) in the above code.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind pulling in another library the [Google Guava API](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) might be a good fit to solve this problem.

```
def partialUnorderedList = ["orange", "blue", "red", "green"] 
Ordering roygbivOrdering = Ordering.explicit("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet")
def partialOrderedList = roygbivOrdering.sortedCopy(partialUnorderedList)
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is to use a closure for comparison, like so:

```
def partialUnorderedList =["orange", "blue", "red","green"]

def order = "roygbiv".inject([:]){ map, letter -> map[letter] = map.size(); map}
def sortedList = partialUnorderedList.sort{ a, b ->
    order[a[0].toLowerCase()] <=> order[b[0].toLowerCase()]
}
```

This creates a hash map of indexes for the first letters of the colors.  The sorting method then looks up the indexes of the first methods, and compares on that.

This only works if you are using unique first letters.  To sort on full names, you might do something like this:

```
def partialUnorderedList =["orange", "blue", "red","green"]

def order = "red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet".split(",").inject([:]){ map, name -> map[name] = map.size(); map}
def sortedList = partialUnorderedList.sort{ a, b ->
    order[a.toLowerCase()] <=> order[b.toLowerCase()]
}
```